# Apache URL Rewriting pagination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am not good at Apache URL Rewriting. I want do some rewrite here.

`http://www.mydomain.com/item/search?words=something&number=1`

=>

`http://www.mydomain.com/item/search/something/1`

And also should be avoid `http://www.mydomain.com/search/something/1` => `http://www.mydomain.com/item/search/something/1` (If there has no `/item/` add it)

Here is my rewrite code.

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /item/search/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(item/search)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ item/search?words=$2&number=$3
```

It show `404` :(

**UPDATE:** here is all my .htaccess file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^comment/(\d+)/?$ /post/comment/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(post/comment)/(\d+)/?$ post/comment?comment=$2

RewriteRule ^rss/(.*)/?$ /item/rss/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(item/rss)/(.*).xml/?$ item/rss.php?rss=$2

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/?$ /item/search/$1/$2 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^(item/search)/([^/]+)/(\d+)/?$ item/search?words=$2&number=$3

RewriteCond %{http_host} ^mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: What's the URL you are typing in your browser's address bar that is returning a 404?

Comment: @Jon Lin, I type: `http://www.mydomain.com/item/search/something/1` return 404.

Comment: And this code is in your htaccess file that's in your document root? And what happens when you go to `http://www.mydomain.com/item/search?words=something&number=1`?

Comment: @Jon Lin, the `.htaccess` is in `document root`, I have rewrite some other rules for other page, they all works. And I can open the page `http://www.mydomain.com/item/search?words=something&number=1`(no 404), thx.

Comment: Can you post your other rules? Are these rules before or after your other rules? Rewrite rules are applied sequentially so what happens to a URI in one rule affects the rules after it.

Comment: @Jon Lin, I have update my question, parse the full rewrite rules.

Comment: Don't know what's wrong then, I put those rules in a blank htaccess file and the above URL that returned 404 for you returned `/item/search?words=something&number=1` for me. No problems at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can not do it in `htaccess`, you should add some code in your wordpress theme `function.php`.

```
function add_my_rewrite() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^item/search/(.+)/(\d+)?$', 'index.php?pagename=item/search&words=$matches[1]&number=$matches[2]', 'top');
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_my_rewrite' );
```

More info about rewriterules for WordPress:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_tag

http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule